# how to load menuitems dynamically in YAHOO.widget.Button?

Tags: javascript, yui

```
         this.widgets.category = new YAHOO.widget.Button(this.id + "-category",
             {
                type: "split",
                menu: this.id + "-category-menu"
             });
```

I am using the code above to create a yui button, after that I updated the options in the menu, but the menu can not be updated. What function can I use to update the menu ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the menu type of button a lot. Typically, we want to rebuild all the options from scratch.  To do this, try the following:

```
// assumes btn is the YAHOO.widget.Button
var menu = btn.getMenu();

// clear existing items
menu.clearContent();

// code to add new menu items using either addItem() or addItems()
menu.addItems([
  { text: "--Not Selected--", value: null },
  { text: "Option 1", value: "1" },
  { text: "Option 2", value: "2" }
]);

// forces menu to render
menu.render();
```